# compare two model instances for equality

Tags: python, model, django-templates, comparison, django-1.8

I know this might sound stupid, but I have looked across the documentation as well as the similar questions and tried everything to no avail. I am missing out on something very fundamental in django I guess.

Here are my model definition

```
class myModel(models.Model):
      CLIENT_ID=models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
      PROFILE_PICTURE = ImageField()
      other fields...

class myNewModel(models.Model):
      CLIENT_ID=models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
      more fields.. etc
```

The CLIENT_ID is supposed to hold a numeric value mostly.

Now in my templates I have to pull out the PROFILE_PICTURE from objects of myModel when the CLIENT_IDs of the two objects match.

What I am trying to do is similar to

```
{% for users in top %}
   {% for client in clients %}
     {% if users.instance.CLIENT_ID == client.instance.CLIENT_ID %}
    <tr>
       <th>{{users.CLIENT_ID}}</th> 
    <th><img src="{{ users.PROFILE_PICTURE.url }}" style="width:auto;height:25px" /></th> 
          {% endif %}{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Where top is an array of objects of myModel, and clients is an array of objects of myNewModel.

In my views.py I have extracted all objects of the models and I am getting other details fine. 
Is that a right way of comparing ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for optional/conditional elements in Django templates:

```
{% if condition %}
    <element />
{% endif %}
```

where `my_model_instance.CLIENT_ID == my_new_model_instance.CLIENT_ID` should be a valid condition.

Comment: Yes I was using the syntax properly, but not the condition. Using your suggestion gives me an always true situation, as in If there are no elements / blank values in my_model_instance.CLIENT_ID I still see the whole page filled with it. Though this is a step further, but I just want to confirm if CharField values can be compared this way.

Comment: To clarify, I have just few objects in myModel, and hundreds of objects in myNewModel In my templates I need to run a for loop to traverse through, running it in nested mode and trying to compare I get an always true output.  Adding / Updating the template code above in query. Thank you so much for responding

Comment: I am still looking for an answer, tried all possible variations that I could think of, cant move beyond this simple thing.